# When using Ternary Operators, is it possible to also assign a value to another variable?

Tags: autohotkey

I tried the following:

```
Hello := "Hello World"
Test := Hello ~= "Hello" ? "Yes, Match!" (Word_Count := 2) : "No Match!"
OutputDebug, % "Test : "Test
OutputDebug, % "Word count is : "Word_Count
```

The console looks like:

```
Test : Yes, Match!2
Word count is : 2
```

It seems that `word_count` does get assigned `2` but the value `2` is also added to `Test`, is it not possible to get a result looks like this?

```
Test : Yes, Match!
Word count is : 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use , and ( )
for example :
(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3)
will run all 3 cmds, but only return result of first cmd

autohotkey document say:

```
(expression)

For a multi-statement expression, 
the result of the first statement is returned. 
For example, (a := 1, b := 2, c := 3) returns 1.
```

```
Comma (multi-statement)

Commas may be used to write multiple sub-expressions on a single line.
This is most commonly used to group together multiple assignments or function calls. 
For example: x:=1, y+=2, ++index, MyFunc(). 
Such statements are executed in order from left to right.
```

## the answer to you is:

```
Test := Hello ~= "Hello" ? ("Yes, Match!" , Word_Count := 2) : "No Match!"
```

ref:
Variables and Expressions - Definition & Usage | AutoHotkey
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm